# Can't change status bar text color in TabbedPage

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have set status bar style to Light. When my MainPage opens, the status bar text becomes black.

My MainPage is a TabbedPage. When I set MainPage to a page that has ContentPage, the status bar text becomes white as expected.

Info.plist

```
<key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
<string>UIStatusBarStyleLightContent</string>
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
```

AppDelegate.cs

```
app.SetStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent, true);
UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent;
```

App.xaml.cs

```
MainPage = new Views.MainPage();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused because I had enclosed child pages in NavigationPages.

MainPage.xaml:

```
<TabbedPage ...>
    <NavigationPage><x:Arguments><local:Page1/></x:Arguments></NavigationPage>
    <NavigationPage><x:Arguments><local:Page2/></x:Arguments></NavigationPage>
</TabbedPage>
```

When I removed the NavigationPages which in my case were unnecessary, the status bar text became white:

```
<TabbedPage ...>
    <local:Page1/>
    <local:Page2/>
</TabbedPage>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the status bar is not the same as the navigation bar.

[image: definitions]

The `theme` (i.e. colours) of the application (for Android) can be set in `App1.Droid.Resources.values.style.xml`.

Here you need to understand which property targets which value in the `styles.xml` file.
[image: file]

[This](https://material.io/guidelines/style/color.html#color-color-system) link in styles.xml contains a lot of information about best practices when styling application colour.

This diagram shows which property will change which value:
[image: tags]

Comment: I know, I have cleaned up my question to avoid confusion.

Comment: @javm You cannot change the status bar in older versions

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the status bar color within the entire app to white you need to change the `View controller-based status bar appearance` property in your info.plist, which by default sets the status bar style at the view controller level and not the application level.

[image: info.plist]

so if this is what you had in your info.plist it should be correct, which you may need to delete the app and clean/rebuild before next deploy

```
<key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
<string>UIStatusBarStyleLightContent</string>
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
```

However, if you need to change the status bar color per `Page` you're probably going to have to write a custom page renderer.

Comment: I have set this. The status bar text is white on the launch screen. When main page opens, the status bar text becomes black.

Answer (score 0):

**The simplest solution**: get the `statusBar` via `keyValue`.

1. Delete the key values you added in `info.plist`.
2. Add the following code in `FinishedLaunching`

   ```
   public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
   {
       global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
       LoadApplication(new App());

       UIView statusBar = UIApplication.SharedApplication.ValueForKey(new NSString("statusBarWindow")).ValueForKey(new NSString("statusBar")) as UIView;
       statusBar.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;

       return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
   }
   ```

[image]

Comment: I want the text to be white, not the background.

Comment: black background and white text?

Comment: Yes. The text becomes white in the Launch Screen, but when the main page opens, the text becomes black. I want it to stay white.

Comment: It always stays white on my side ,  try to set the launch screen to none in info.plist.

Comment: Then the launch screen becomes only a black screen (w/ white status bar text). When the main app opens, the status bar text turns black again.

Comment: Which simulator and os version are you testing on ?

Comment: Simulator version 10 (iPhone 7 iOS 11) on macOS 10.13.3. Developing on VS 2017 on Windows 10.

Comment: My MainPage is a TabbedPage but when I changed MainPage to a page with ContentPage, the status bar text becomes white as expected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166873/discussion-between-cole-xia-msft-and-javm).